Error Using Ollama Docker Image with LangChain to Perform LLaMA Model Inference
I'm trying to use the official Ollama Docker image to run a Python script that performs inference using the llama3.1 model from Ollama with LangChain. My script performs some operations on a Pandas DataFrame and then uses the LLaMA model to answer questions based on the DataFrame's content.
I am pretty new to working with Docker, and created a simple script with the help of ChatGPT 4o and the reference in Docker on using ollama.
I received the error message:
ERROR: failed to solve: python:3.9-slim: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.9-slim": EOF

Here's a simplified version of my script:
import pandas as pd
from langchain_ollama.llms import OllamaLLM
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.schema.runnable import RunnableLambda

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['Product A', 'Product B'], 'description': ['Description A', 'Description B']})

# Initialize the LLaMA model using Ollama
model = OllamaLLM(model="llama3.1")

# Define the prompt template
question_template = """
Description: {description}
Question: {question}
"""

# Create a PromptTemplate
prompt_to_list_creation = PromptTemplate(
    template=question_template,
    input_variables=["description", "question"]
)

# Define a function to parse the response into a string
def parse_response(response) -> str:
    return response.strip() if isinstance(response, str) else response.content.strip()

# Create a RunnableLambda to parse the response
parse_lambda = RunnableLambda(func=parse_response)

# Chain the model and parsing function
expression_with_parsing = prompt_to_list_creation | model | parse_lambda

# Function to get answers based on the DataFrame input
def get_answers_from_df(df: pd.DataFrame, question: str):
    answers = []
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        input_data = {"description": row['description'], "question": question}
        response = expression_with_parsing.invoke(input_data)
        answers.append(response)
    return answers

# Example usage
question = "What are the key features?"
answers = get_answers_from_df(df, question)
print(answers)


I tried to use the following Dockerfile to pull the llama3.1 model and run the script:
# Use the official Ollama image to pull the model
FROM ollama/ollama:latest as ollama

RUN ollama pull llama3.1

# Use a Python image to set up the environment and run the script
FROM python:3.9-slim
COPY --from=ollama /root/.ollama/models /root/.ollama/models
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY script.py .
CMD ["python", "script.py"]

With requirements.txt
networkx
langchain
langchain_ollama


That error message suggests a connectivity problem between the Docker daemon and Docker Hub; it's probably not related to your code at all.  Are you in some sort of restricted network environment, maybe where outbound requests need to go via a proxy?  Your setup seems like it should work in a standalone Python environment, do you actually need Docker to run it?

I actually don't need Docker for this specific code and it runs locally without Docker. I am mainly interested in having this code running in Docker for additional development.
